# 'You need to connect to a chain with a runtime that supports contracts

Tags: substrate-contracts-node

While connecting to substrate node gives the following error
`You need to connect to a chain with a runtime that supports contracts`

I have started the substrte node using  `./target/release/node-template --dev`
and strted the front-end using `yarn start`

THe code executed is

```
import fs from "fs";
import { create } from 'ipfs-http-client';

import { ContractPromise } from '@polkadot/api-contract';
import { Keyring } from '@polkadot/api';
import { ApiPromise, WsProvider } from '@polkadot/api';

const metadata = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./metadata.json'));

main()
async function main() {
    const wsProvider = new WsProvider('ws://localhost:9944');
   
    const api = await ApiPromise.create({provider:wsProvider});
    console.log(wsProvider.isConnected); // to check whether connected or not
    console.log(api.isConnected);

    const address = '5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY';
    const contract = new ContractPromise(api,metadata, address);
}
```

Executing the above doce gives output with error

```
true
true
file:///Users/123/Documents/Study%20related/Learning-JS/ipfs_ink/node_modules/@polkadot/api-contract/base/Base.js:14
      throw new Error('You need to connect to a chain with a runtime that supports contracts');
            ^

Error: You need to connect to a chain with a runtime that supports contracts
    at new Base (file:///Users/123/Documents/Study%20related/Learning-JS/ipfs_ink/node_modules/@polkadot/api-contract/base/Base.js:14:13)
    at new Contract (file:///Users/123/Documents/Study%20related/Learning-JS/ipfs_ink/node_modules/@polkadot/api-contract/base/Contract.js:37:5)
    at new ContractPromise (file:///Users/123/Documents/Study%20related/Learning-JS/ipfs_ink/node_modules/@polkadot/api-contract/promise/index.js:19:5)
    at main (file:///Users/123/Documents/Study%20related/Learning-JS/ipfs_ink/index_1.js:31:22)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Though i am running the node i am not sure whether i miss anything

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running the [Substrate Node Template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template), and it is not supporting Smart Contracts by default.

In order to have the Smart Contracts to functionality in your node you must install the [Contacts pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/contracts).

Check how to do it in this [How-to-guide](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/pallet-design/add-contracts-pallet/), or use the [substrate-contracts-node](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node).

[This tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/smart-contracts/prepare-your-first-contract/) demonstrates how to build a basic smart contract to run on a Substrate-based chain.

Comment: i tried to modify as mentioned in [link]  (https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/work-with-pallets/contracts-pallet/) to enable the runtime contract. But getting error in the 'Implement the Contracts configuration trait' setion compilation.  related to ```unresolved import `pallet_contracts::DefaultContractAccessWeight`
    --> /home/ubuntu/substrate/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:44:5 ```

Comment: Check the version when import the pallets, in the tutorial uses the polkadot-v0.9.28 but it has to be the same as the rest of the pallets you have in the Cargo.toml