# Error while running the RPC call

Tags: pallet, pallet-contracts, substrate-contracts-node

while running the flipper contract I get the following error

```
{ Err: { Module: { index: '9', error: '0x06000000' } } }
```

What does it mean?

I searched https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-errors
but didn't get any idea.

I am using RPC all to connect **metadata.json** through javascript program.

Using the method mentioned in [polkadot rpc](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api-contract/start/code) I am able to instantiate the contract (code promise), ia mable to run blueprint promise. But when i run the contract mentioned in [doc](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api-contract/start/contract.read/) I get the error mentioned above

Comment: Can you please give more details about the steps you took to get to this point? Like which pallets you were interacting with, what call you made, etc... In general, if you use a UI like Polkadot JS Apps, these errors will be decoded for you.

Comment: I deployed the code in the **substrate contract node**, which works well and execute the contract. Then I tried to run it by using the runtime pallet used in [link](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/work-with-pallets/contracts-pallet/). In the runtime, I access the contract from the **'metadata.json'** file created by compiling the smart contract written in Ink. The error comes when running it from the node application and accessing it using **metadata.json.**  i use the  **metadata.json.** created by running the flipper contract

Answer (score 1):

Assuming (big assumption) you are running the template node (as [you said previously](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5882/you-need-to-connect-to-a-chain-with-a-runtime-that-supports-contracts)) and you just added the Contracts pallet to it with `index: 9`, the error you are getting is `ContractNotFound`, meaning that no contract was found in the specified address. Probably you are trying to call a contract on-chain without deploying it first. I recommend you to follow carefully the steps in [this tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/smart-contracts/prepare-your-first-contract/).

Comment: I deployed the code in the **substrate contract node**, which works well and execute the contract. Then I tried to run it by using the runtime pallet used in [link](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/work-with-pallets/contracts-pallet/). In the runtime, I access the contract from the **'metadata.json'** file created by compiling the smart contract written in Ink. The error comes when running it from the node application and accessing it using **metadata.json.**  i use the  **metadata.json.** created by running the flipper contract

Comment: I have instantiated the contract and run blueprint mentioned on [link](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api-contract/start/code), and run the blueprint. I suppose my contract run on chain I suppose. I am able to access it in [ink](https://polkadot.js.org/) development node. The error appears while running the contract mentioned in [link](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api-contract/start/contract.read/)